# cv2.imwrite(filename, gray) TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'

Tags: python

cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO0tt.png)

Comment: The pro just help me with this error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post images, but paste and format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv2.threshold` returns 2-tuple of value, array. You should replace

```
gray = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

using

```
ret,gray = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

c.f. [OpenCV Thresholding tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)